# How to send email using activemq

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, activemq-classic, jakarta-mail

I am new to this activemq, I want to send an email for every hour using activemq data. How to configure this scheduling process in activemq? Is there any tutorial for this action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty generic question, but I can give you some outlining hints regarding the scheduling using Spring:

1. Include in your dependencies the Spring Context Support package if you don't already have it. If you're using Maven then you can find the dependency [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support).
2. Create a org.quartz.Job implementation that does the actual sending of the mail. I would use the Spring-provided QuartzJobBean. **NOTE:** There is actually a org.quartz.jobs.ee.mail.SendMailJob class that does mail sending. 
   In both cases you can retrieve the data from your ActiveMQ instance and generate the desired content for the mail.

   ```
   public class SendMailFromActiveMQ extends QuartzJobBean {
   @Override
   protected void doExecuteInternal(ApplicationContext applicationContext, JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
       //generate content for email
       //send email
   }
   ```

   }
3. Attach your org.quartz.Job implementation to a JobDetailBean bean in your application context definition:

```xml
<bean id="sendEmailJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="ro.oneandone.hosting.ebusiness.nlt.sending.quartz.SendRegularMessagesJob" />
</bean>
```

1. Create a CronTrigger for the previous JobDetailBean bean:

```xml
    <bean id="sendEmailCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="sendEmailJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0/1 * * ?" />
        <!-- Run every hour -->
</bean>
```

1. To finalize, you register the job to a SchedulerFactoryBean:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="sendEmailCronTrigger"/>
    </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

I repeat, this is just an outline. you have to adapt the code to your needs, which I hope i understood correctly, since you tagged this question with "Spring".

If you need the following links are for further information regarding Quartz scheduling:

- [Quartz tutorials](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/)
- [Spring scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.5/reference/scheduling.html)

Comment: For the life of me I can't understand why the StackOverflow editor won't let me continue the indexes for the steps.